# How to average 2 time series' in R?

Tags: r

Suppose I have 2 different time series' in R.

1)

> Jan 18------Feb 18------Mar 18------Apr 18
>
> -----1------------2--------------4-------------10

And 2)

> Jan 18------Feb 18------Mar 18------Apr 18
>
> -----4------------6--------------10-------------4

How can I generate the time series based on the average of the 2?

I.e.

> Jan 18------Feb 18------Mar 18------Apr 18
>
> -----2.5------------4--------------7-------------7

My thought was to somehow extract the values into a vector for the two series' then take the average then make a new time series based on this but I couldn't get that to work.

I 'm not sure but I feel this should be really easy to do as in one line of code but I can't figure it out.

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we have the series A and B defined reproducibly as shown.  Then just add them and divide by 2:

```
A <- ts(c(1, 2, 4, 10), start = 2018, frequency = 12)
B <- ts(c(4, 6, 10, 4), start = 2018, frequency = 12)
(A+B)/2
```

giving:

```
     Jan Feb Mar Apr
2018 2.5 4.0 7.0 7.0
```